# Electron - battery level change event in macOS

Tags: electron

I’m developing a battery management app for macOS built on Electron, but I still don’t really know how I can cleanly keep battery charge levels updated.

I’ve tried implementing a LaunchAgent that updates the  battery level, reading it using `pmset -g batt` and writing it in a JSON file every 60 seconds. This file is watched by an instance of the [chokidar library](https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar): when the file changes the app gets updated, too. (I’ve done this way 'cause in the file there are other data I need for the app).

However, I’d like to find a cleaner and more “native” way to do this, which supports a seamless and instant update of battery level.

I’ve seen that in Electron it’s possible to [subscrive to native notifications of macOS](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/system-preferences#systempreferencessubscribenotificationevent-callback-macos), but I don't even know if is there any available for this purpose.

Otherwise, I could watch for changes at any system file which gets updated when the battery level changes, but I couldn't find any.

I’m also interested in any different method.

PS: I can’t use the [Battery Status API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Battery_Status_API) as the app doesn't keep any open window (it's a menubar app), so I need to manage the event in the main process.